# ASP.NET MVC: viewmodel and domain object. From their and back again

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

This is my domain classes:

```
public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public List<ChildItem> ChildItems { get; set; }
}
public class ChildItem
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

They are mapped to database tables using Nhibernate. This is my viewmodels:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public List<ChildItemViewModel> ChildItems { get; set; }
}
public class ChildItemViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

It's very easy to populate viewmodel from domain object using Automapper. Then on client I add new childItemViewModels to itemViewModel and then on server I need to save my changes to database: it's required to populate domain object from viewmodel and reverse mapping doesn't help because I need to create domain objects or get domain objects from repository to add in collection. How to populate your domain objects from viewmodels in complex cases (with child collections) "by a smart way"?

Comment: I've been continually frustrated with this as well. There is a big gap between the view model and the domain model, that so far, requires manual mapping. In my opinion, the two-way binding in ASP.NET MVC is not _true_ two way binding because domain models in the view model are disconnected from the domain layer completely. I've been searching for some sort of custom model binder that would do this, but has so far come up empty handed. I'd love to see some answers to this question that don't involve hand writing code.

Comment: I searched Google for "integrate asp.net mvc model binder with entity framework" and came across this StackOverflow question that may be useful: [Model Binding With Entity Framework (ASP.NET MVC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975329/model-binding-with-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc). I know it's not NHibernate, but it may give you the basic mechanism.

Comment: I usually use a service layer to generate my view model. You can put all your transforming logic in there.